# How to get the branch coverage of Jest unit test for generic parameter in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest

I've been aiming for 100% branch coverage of Jest unit test on my codes, but I am stuck at writing test codes to cover divergence of generic parameter.

Here is the method.

```
  async setRedisCache<T>(
    key: string,
    value: T,
    options?: CachingConfig,
  ): Promise<T> {
    return await this.redisServer.set<T>(key, value, options);
  }
```

There's a generic type T, and the jest coverage report says the value parameter type is not covered and the %Branch doesn't accomplish 100% because of it as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl1zK.png)

Does anybody know how I could write a unit test to cover generic parameter to get 100% branch coverage?

I tried to write several unit tests with different type parameters but it's still uncovered.